# laravel 5.4 page load issue in local server

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel 5.4 and doing development on previously developed project. For installation I installed a fresh copy of laravel 5.4 using composer after that i replaced all the files except .env & .env.example file. But the page load time is much more compared to live server ie in local machine its taking 3 min 28 sec. I tried by changing the environment to local, development & production and altered the debug status as well. I also cleared normal and configuration cache and also optimized it as well, But nothing works its not calling any external file which is taking time. After loading the page the first page called through ajax is talking time. There is not any code issue as the same code is working fine in live server. Please guide where I am making mistake, My Current PHP versions & other details are listed below :

```
OS : Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit
PHP Version 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
Apache 2.0 Handler 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Laravel : 5.4
```